# Computer Vision techniques for geometrical information

Tags: geometry, computer-vision, convex-hull, convex

I am trying to research and implement some computer vision techniques e.g. motion tracking for a set of arbitrary points in 2D. I am producing a convex hull for the set of points I know and a convex hull for the set of points that it could potentially map to. I am looking for resources that would help me in comparing how similar the two hulls are and then if similar enough how they actually map on to each other?
Any information on where to find good resources/books that discuss this style of algorithm and potentially more complex algorithms in this area would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [iterative closest point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_Closest_Point) to match 2d and 3d point sets in the past.